# Using refman document class within a different document class

Tags: document-classes

I want to include a reference manual for my code within a document that uses the `report` class, in the appendices. Is that possible?

Comment: you can only use one document class per document. What features do you need that are not in `report`

Comment: I just thought that refman is the standard way to document code. Is there a package that will facilitate writing a manual, that I can use within the document class?

Comment: I'd never hard of `refman` there is a `refart.cls` in a `refman` directory in texlive is that the one you meant? looking at the source it's only a minor modification of `report`, I ask again what commands/environments do you need a "a manual" isn't very specific, a software manual, and user manual for a camera are likely to need different constructs.

Comment: You can always produce the manual separately and then include the compiled manual into your document using something like `pdfpages` (if you are compiling directly to PDF).

Comment: To be more specific, I would like to document the functionality of some MATLAB classes that I have written.

Comment: If you want to document code and functionalities I would recommend some kind of `doxygen` as an external tool or the usage of `listings` package, which has syntax markup for `Matlab`

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little bit unclear:

Writing a reference manual for software most times requires a package like 
`listings` or `minted` or the `tcolorbox` facilities -- all are suited for code snippets or small routines or very small scripts etc.

Documentation of many software procedures/object classes can be done with `doxygen`, for example, which provides class browsers -- I don't recommend the direct usage of LaTeX for this -- I had to document a software package I wrote (in 2006) with `C++` and `Qt` and used `doxygen`.

`doxygen` allows to incorporate `LaTeX` or `HTML` markup for export to `.pdf` or `.html` pages.

If algorithms shall be presented, this can be done with various packages like `algorithmic` or `algpseudocode`.